# iOS 10 local notification not showing max time like iOS 9 does in Background state

Tags: ios, voip, ios10

I am doing VoIP application. If my application is in background state, I am  playing incoming call with local notification. Its worked fine in iOS 9. Its showing banner minimum long duration. But, in iOS 10, its showing only near 10 seconds and disappearing banner automatically.

How to show maximum time local notification banner in iOS 10 like iOS 9 does.

Comment: Please provide the code you are using. Also state whether you're talking about notifications on the lock screen or while using other apps (they behave very differently).

Comment: @jcaron, thanks for your reply, i am talking about notifications on background state. check this  https://www.pastiebin.com/57e915004e0b7